# How to fix the Ajax calender Month in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I want to dynamically fix the calender extender month, so that user can only select  the date from the month shown

Note:

1. calender extender is in gridview.
2. dynamically set the month on the basis of selected month from combobox located outside gridview.
3. User should not be able to change month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide month navigation the calendar control has property **ShowNextPrevMonth**  set it to FALSE.
To hide days of another month in calendar you have to manage it in DayRender Event.
**VB example.**

```
Protected Sub yourCalendar_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DayRenderEventArgs) Handles yourCalendar.DayRender
    If e.Day.IsOtherMonth Then
    e.Cell.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```